# Cannot do the SQL query in python via sqlite3 to find out the unique numbers

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a database. These database has two tables.

One table is `music`.

| name | Date | Edition | Song_ID | Singer_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LA | 01.05.2009 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Second | 13.07.2009 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| Mexico | 13.07.2009 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| Let's go | 13.09.2009 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| Hello | 18.09.2009 | 1 | 5 | (4,5) |
| Don't give up | 12.02.2010 | 2 | 6 | (5,6) |
| ZIC ZAC | 18.03.2010 | 2 | 7 | 7 |
| Blablabla | 14.04.2010 | 2 | 8 | 2 |
| Oh la la | 14.05.2011 | 3 | 9 | 4 |
| Food First | 14.05.2011 | 3 | 10 | 5 |
| La Vie est.. | 17.06.2011 | 3 | 11 | 8 |
| Jajajajajaja | 13.07.2011 | 3 | 12 | 9 |

And another table called `singer`

| Singer | nationality | Singer_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JT Watson | USA | 1 |
| Rafinha | Brazil | 2 |
| Juan Casa | Spain | 3 |
| Kidi | USA | 4 |
| Dede | USA | 5 |
| Briana | USA | 6 |
| Jay Ado | UK | 7 |
| Dani | Australia | 8 |
| Mike Rich | USA | 9 |

Now I would like to find out how many Songs are there. I gave that code, but it says invalid sytax??

```
SELECT DISTINCT Song_ID FROM music
```

The invalid syntax is near DISTINCT

I create the database like these, maybe that is why it has error:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('musicten.db')  
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS singer
          ([Singer_ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [Singer] TEXT, [nationality] TEXT)
          ''')
          
c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS music
          ([SONG_ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [SINGER_ID] INTEGER SECONDARY KEY, [name] TEXT, [Date] DATE, [EDITION] INTEGER)
          ''')
                     
conn.commit()





import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('musicten.db') 
c = conn.cursor()
                   
c.execute('''
          INSERT INTO singer (Singer_ID, Singer,nationality)

                VALUES
                (1,'JT Watson',' USA'),
                (2,'Rafinha','Brazil'),
                (3,'Juan Casa','Spain'),
                (4,'Kidi','USA'),
                (5,'Dede','USA')
          ''')

c.execute('''
          INSERT INTO music (Song_ID,Singer_ID, name, Date,Edition)

                VALUES
                (1,1,'LA',01/05/2009,1),
                (2,2,'Second',13/07/2009,1),
                (3,1,'Mexico',13/07/2009,1),
                (4,3,'Let"s go',13/09/2009,1),
                (5,(4,5),'Hello',18/09/2009,1)
          ''')
```

But I don't think, because this works fine. I can not do the sql code

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is very basic SQL.)

Comment: I used the sql in python, so sqlite3

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT Song_ID FROM music` is valid. If you get a syntactical error then the problem is with your Python code which you did not post.

Comment: I never saw the syntax `SECONDARY KEY` before and `SECONDARY` is not listed as [keyword in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Is it translated to a UNIQUE INDEX by your python library?

Comment: The number of songs is `SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfSongs FROM music`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a count query here:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Song_ID) FROM music;
```

Assuming that every `Song_ID` be unique in the `music` table, you don't even need a distinct count; a regular count will also work:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(Song_ID) FROM music;
```

Comment: But it also says invalid syntax near COUNT now

Comment: ...then you may not be running my answer.  Both the queries I gave you are legitimate and should at least execute.

Comment: I run your answer, but I got again the  error message

Comment: It must be some operator error.  What is your database (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.)?  Also, how are you executing the query?  Are you doing this from a Python script or directly against the database?

Comment: I do it in python

Comment: _Edit_ your question and show us the Python code you are running.

Comment: I used the same python code as you wrote here

Comment: Hi, Thank you, it has worked now, there was a problem with the wifi connection in my country. For that reason everything was invalid

Answer (score -1):

I would also try
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Song_ID) from music;

Comment: Why? `SELECT COUNT(Song_ID) from music` returns only 1 row with 1 column. What is the point of DISTINCT?